# Windows installer custom action call WCF to get value from remote failed.(NoEndpoint found exception)

Tags: wcf, windows-installer

I am using windows installer to deploy my application. And i have add a custom action to access a WCF service from remote server. While installing application i found endpoind not found exception.

```
ServiceReference.testContractsClient client;
var wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false);
//End point i take from user input
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(ctlWebServiceUrl.Text);
wsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
client = new ServiceReference.testContractsClient(wsBinding, endpointAddress);
client.test(); //method call
```

If i connect to LAN (network) it works, same installer work on all machine.
Windows XP Professional on only one PC have issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the problem exists with the proxy, we need to set to `false` the `usedefaultproxy` flag of endpoint object.